# Reimplementing Microsoft SQL Server `PWDENCRYPT`/`PWDCOMPARE` in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, hash, passwords

I've been on a painful journey over the last couple of weeks. But I reached my destination. In the hope that I'm able to help others reach this point faster, and in a less stressful way, I'll share my results.

### The Background Story

We're currently rebuilding our platform in Python and Django. The existing platform is based on .NET and related MS technologies. We're soon preparing to launch, and part of that is also migrating user data from the old to the new platform.

In the old system, user passwords are hashed and verified using the built-in [`PWDENCRYPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`PWDCOMPARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdcompare-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) functions of Microsoft SQL Server.

As we want the transition to be as frictionless as possible for our users, we of course also want them to not have to reset their password after we launch. So I got the seemingly simple task to [create a custom Django password hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-hasher) that is able to verify user entered passwords againts the hashes from `PWDENCRYPT`.

First I set out to find some documentation on what those MS SQL functions actually do. It seems to officially not be very well documented what happens behind the scenes (if at all), and according to the docs you're not really supposed to use it:

> PWDENCRYPT is an older function and might not be supported in a future release of SQL Server. Use HASHBYTES instead. HASHBYTES provides more hashing algorithms.

Fortunately, [a couple of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786029/sql-server-pwdencrypt-value-comparison) [Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173329/how-to-decrypt-a-password-from-sql-server) were able to guide me in the right direction, although not all the way, due to errors in their explanations and examples, which sent me on several detours.

After spending way too much time on it, I gave up. But then a colleague gave it a try and found the missing key: The passwords must be encoded using `UTF-16LE`. A detail I missed, but might be obvious to someone who is used to work in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

### The Solution

So, let's go through it step by step.

#### `PWDENCRYPT`

Let's try generating a password hash in SQL Server and look at the result:

```
SELECT PWDENCRYPT('very-secret-passwørd')
GO

0x02008D6818FFB31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893843
```

The result consists of 4 parts:

`0x` an indication that this is a hexadecimal value.

`0200` tells us the version of the hashing algorithm used. In this case, it tells us that it's hashed using `SHA-512` (or `SHA2_512` in the vocabulary of SQL Server). If the header is `0100`, it is instead hashed using `SHA1`.

`8D6818FF` is the salt for the hash.

`B31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893843` is the actual salted and hashed password.

#### `PWDCOMPARE`

This function is used to compare a password against a salted hash. Let's try it out:

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE('very-secret-passwørd', 0x02008D6818FFB31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893843)
GO

-----------
          1
```

`1` is a boolean value, indicating that the password matched the hashed password. Using another hash, the result will be `0`:

```
SELECT PWDCOMPARE('very-secret-passwørd', 0x02008D6818FFB31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893800)
GO

-----------
          0
```

I changed the last 2 digits of the hash to be `00` and got a `0` back: The password did not match the hashed password. So far so good.

#### Reimplementing in SQL Using `HASHBYTES`

Now, in order to understand what's going on, I sort of reimplemented this with `HASHBYTES` based on the information found in the previously mentioned Stack Overflow questions:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'very-secret-passwørd' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x8D6818FF))

0xB31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893843
```

Yay! I get the same hash. All good.

#### Reimplementing in Python

And then the grand finale: Doing the same in Python. This is where I ended up spending days in agony, but I will save you from it and show you what to do instead.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha512("very-secret-passwørd".encode("utf-16le") + bytes.fromhex("8D6818FF")).hexdigest()
'b31baaa6f849583a0c1319e1e73a260525cfec22d4bc9fe2fbcc535c682342634d5b87b2ed1a1da2c63b7fed3ccdfc82de31dd5670ccac9ba7ba5866eb893843'
```

There you go! Adding `.upper()` to the result allows us to compare the hashes from SQL Server and Python:

```
>>> hashlib.sha512("very-secret-passwørd".encode("utf-16le") + bytes.fromhex("8D6818FF")).hexdigest().upper() == "B31BAAA6F849583A0C1319E1E73A260525CFEC22D4BC9FE2FBCC535C682342634D5B87B2ED1A1DA2C63B7FED3CCDFC82DE31DD5670CCAC9BA7BA5866EB893843"
True
```

Comment: Your queries don't appear to be valid, you are using double quotes ('"') as a literal string identifier, however, T-SQL uses single quotes (`'`) for literal strings; double quotes are for delimit identifying **objects**.

Comment: Works for me, but I'll change it in order to not confuse anyone, thanks :)

Comment: `SELECT HASHBYTES("SHA2_512", "very-secret-passwørd" + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), 0x8D6818FF))` certainly won't work: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u2o8Zvv9)

Comment: Certainly it does. Trust me, I've run these queries a million times with double qoutes without any problems. But I have changed it now to avoid confusion.

Comment: This sounds like you might be running queries with `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` then; a very bad habit.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but I hope you guys are not trying to solve my problem by teaching me about quotes in SQL, because that wasn't the problem.

Comment: The point is that your SQL was very unlikely to run in most people's environment, which would make the answer not useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250237/discussion-between-decibyte-and-larnu).

Comment: Solid work, @decibyte! Out of curiosity, how did you figure out the hashing algorithm, which bytes were the salt, etc? That is, was it experimentation or did you find it documented somewhere?

Comment: Ben, thanks! Most of it was described in this answer to one of the SO questions I'm linking to in my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154134/173937 - but I couldn't find any official documentation for it.